# Is it correct to use a past tense verb before a present tense verb like this?

Tags: tenses, sequence-of-tenses, past-vs-present

> Every morning right after I **went** to the bathroom, I **tell** myself

In the sentence above should *went* and *tell* agree?

Is above correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; *went* should be replaced with *go*. *Tell* is present-tense, as is *go*. *Went* is past-tense.

> Every morning, right after I **go** to the bathroom, I **tell** myself…

If you were referring to a specific instance in the past, you could write,

> Yesterday morning, right after I **went** to the bathroom, I **told** myself…

Comment: You could also use the present perfect: "Every morning, right after I have gone to the bathroom, I tell myself..."

Comment: …or "Every morning, right after going to the bathroom, I tell myself…"

Answer (score 3):

The sentence you quoted should use the same tense for both verbs. The actions are more or less contemporaneous.

> - Every morning right after I **went** to the bathroom, I **told** myself…
> - Every morning right after I **go** to the bathroom, I **tell** myself…

Because the first sentence above is in the past tense, it implies you no longer have this habit.